# Minimize the Area

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The lower corner of a page is to folded to reach the opposite inner edge. 
We have to find the width of the folded part if the Area of the folded part is minimum.

Now how I proceeded:

Let the width of the page be $1$.
Let the folded part be $x$. 
And the angle of the part folded be $\theta$.

Now I found a relation between $x$ and $\theta$ and thus wrote the area entirely as a function  of tan($\theta$) and minimized it.

What I want to know is of  other different  ways to do this.

Here's a sketch :

[image]

Just in case someone  wants to check their answers,  the width x comes out to be 2/3.

Comment: Please leave a sketch or photo

Comment: @Narasimham I have added a link, but I have seen that some questions  have images directly in the question,  How to do that?

Comment: One way is to have someone with more reputation add the image for you. Done now! I also cropped the image a bit, to save screen space.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks

Comment: @user307178 How is it a maximization situation? Maximum area is one half the full paper area whether you fold length-wise or breadth-wise.

Comment: @Narasimham '' Minimize'' the Area

Comment: Do you mean a solution without calculus?

Comment: @Aretino Yes I would love that

Answer (score 2):

I suggest working with $\theta':={\pi\over2}-\theta$ instead, and putting $\tan\theta'=:\tau$. You then have
$${1-x\over x}=\cos(\pi-2\theta)=\cos(2\theta')={1-\tau^2\over 1+\tau^2}$$
and therefore ${\displaystyle x={1+\tau^2\over2}}$.
The area in question then comes to
$$A={1\over2}x\cdot{x\over\tau}={(1+\tau^2)^2\over 8\tau}\ .$$
It turns out that $A$ is minimal when $\tau^2={1\over3}$, or $\theta'=30^\circ$, so that $x={2\over3}$.

The simplicity of the result opens up a chance that it can be obtained also using some geometric reasoning.

Comment: I did nearly the same thing. I  am more Interested in other ways of approach.

Comment: What do you have in mind? It's only seeing the result that gives some hope for "another way".

Comment: Yes that's what led me to believe that there would be an  another way to get that.